# React-virtualized: how to use minWidth only

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have `<Column />` with width attr. How I can make last column width equal to all available width (I mean all other free space in block)? Try to set `minWidth`, but width required...

If I set big amount of width, my other columns on small screen reduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`Column` docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Column.md#column). The relevant ones are:

```
flexGrow    Number  Flex grow style; defaults to 0
flexShrink  Number  Flex shrink style; defaults to 1
maxWidth    Number  Maximum width of column; this property will only be used if :flexGrow is greater than 0
minWidth    Number  Minimum width of column
width       Number  Flex basis (width) for this column; This value can grow or shrink based on flexGrow and flexShrink properties
```

In this case, I believe you just need to add `flexGrow={1}` to your last column. `Table` uses flex box layout.

FWIW this is also how the [react-virtualized `Table` demo](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Table) works. You can see its source code [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/b0fb959cf2614a5f70e031551076514e45287ae9/source/Table/Table.example.js#L219).

Comment: I don't see flexGrow, my fault. This is exactly what I need.